# Cannot send user's input containing an apostrophe to sqlite3-database (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've been looking at some similar questions on here but can't seem to find any working solutions.

My app lets the user write whatever they want in a UITextField and send it to a sqlite3-database. However, if it contains an apostrophe, it won't send it.

I know putting two apostrophes in the text field works but that isn't user-friendly at all... Any ideas?

**Thanks!**

```
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    // Prepare the query string.
    // If the recordIDToEdit property has value other than -1, then create an update query. Otherwise create an insert query.
    NSString *query;
    if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', %@)", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text];
    }
    else{
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', date=%@ where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtDate.text, self.recordIDToEdit];
    }
```

Comment: It looks dangerous for me. You're making a SQLite client in iOS ?

Comment: It's just for practice, but why is it dangerous?

Comment: Because of little Bobby Tables, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never do it this way! Always remember little Bobby Tables:
[Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Use [prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) to insert data into a database, never concatenate / build your statements on your own; take a look here:

[Objective-C: Fast SQLite Inserts with Prepared Statements for Escaped Apostrophes and SQL Injection Protection](http://www.schiffhauer.com/objective-c-fast-sqlite-inserts-with-prepared-statements-for-escaped-apostrophes-and-dependency-injection-protection/)

---

**On your own risk,** you could use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to escape each single quote with two single quotes:

```
NSString *firstName = self.txtFirstname.text;
firstName = [firstName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];

if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', %@)", firstName, self.txtDate.text];
}
else{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', date=%@ where peopleInfoID=%d", firstName, self.txtDate.text, self.recordIDToEdit];
}
```

Comment: See answer above, use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`

Answer (score 0):

You should always do some kind of "string escaping" when concatenating a query. As for the safety, look up for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote my answer if it was helpful. Thanks :)